# Remove an item from ListView in Android: some onClickListeners stop working (EDIT: they are called all at once later)

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have a `ListView` with a custom layout. This layout has an `EditText` and a `Button` to delete the row.

I want the user to be able to add items to the list (click in an outside button) or remove an item from the list (click in the row's button). To be able to delete a certain row (I need its position) I decided to implement an `OnClickListener` where I store the item position as a variable.

**The problem is, once I delete a row, all the following rows listeners' stop working. Why is that?**

Since I'll have to retrieve the `EditText`'s values when the user decides he has finished, I decided to implement my custom adapter and store the rows in there (ArrayList).

This is my Activity:

```
    private ListView mList;
    private TemplateFieldsAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_template);

        customFieldsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.customFieldsContent);

        numFields = 0;
        childs = new ArrayList<View>();

        //      mDragListen = new MyDragEventListener();

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.customFieldsList);
        adapter = new TemplateFieldsAdapter(this);

        mList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mList.setClickable(false);
    }

    public void AddField(View v){
        adapter.addItem();
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

And this is my adapter:

```
public class TemplateFieldsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    private ArrayList<View> rows;
    private int count;

    private Context mContext;

    public TemplateFieldsAdapter(Context context){
        mContext = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        rows = new ArrayList<View>();
        count = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    @Override
    public View getItem(int position) {
        return rows.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(rows.size() <= position || rows.get(position) == null){ // If the View is not cached
            // Inflates the Common View from XML file
            rows.add(position, this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_field, null));
            rows.get(position).findViewById(R.id.removeImg).setOnClickListener(new DeleteRow(position));
        }       

        return rows.get(position);
    }

    public void addItem(){
        count ++;
    }

    private class DeleteRow implements View.OnClickListener{

        private int position;

        public DeleteRow(int pos){
            this.position = pos;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            rows.remove(position);
            count --;

            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

I know that I should update the listeners when I remove an item (since the position changes), but I removed the code to made it easier to understand.

If I add 4 items and then I remove the item at position 1 **the listeners of the positions 2 and 3 (now they are at positions 1 and 2) stop working, the onClick function isn't called**. Anybody knows how to fix it?

Thanks!

[EDIT] I just found out something interesting. In the example above I said that the onClick function isn't called, and it isn't. But if then I click the outside Button (to add a new item) **all the onClicks that weren't called at called at once**. This is really weird. [/EDIT]

Comment: May I ask why you are keeping a List of `Views` instead of data they display ?

Comment: Because the data displayed is initially empty (rows have an EditText), the user fills it. I decided to store the Views and check them all at the end instead of having to update an ArrayList of strings each time the user modifies an EditText.

Answer (score 0):

use delete like that

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            View row = null;
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.one_result_details_row, parent, false);

            // inflate other items here : 
            Button deleteButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.Details_Button01);
             deleteButton.setTag(position);

            deleteButton.setOnClickListener(
                new Button.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Integer index = (Integer) view.getTag();
                        items.remove(index.intValue());  
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }
            );
```

Comment: Still the same, I don't get the click events.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I found to solve it is create the Views each time getView is called:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(rows.size() <= position || rows.get(position) == null){ // If the View is not cached
            rows.add(position, this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_field, null));
        }       
        else{
            View newView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.template_field, null);
            ((TextView)newView.findViewById(R.id.etFieldName)).setText(((TextView)rows.get(position).findViewById(R.id.etFieldName)).getText());
            ((TextView)newView.findViewById(R.id.etFieldUnit)).setText(((TextView)rows.get(position).findViewById(R.id.etFieldUnit)).getText());

            rows.remove(position);
            rows.add(position, newView);
        }

        rows.get(position).findViewById(R.id.removeImg).setTag(position);
        rows.get(position).findViewById(R.id.removeImg).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                rows.remove(index.intValue());
                count --;  
                mContext.updateList();
            }
        });

        rows.get(position).findViewById(R.id.etFieldName).requestFocus();

        return rows.get(position);
    }
```